# How to remain a checkbox "checked" in dataTables after move rows up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a dataTable that each row in it has a checkbox and up or down buttons to move rows. But if I check a checkbox and then move the row, checkbox change to unchecked state.

How can I prevent this event and hold the checkbox checked?

```
{ name: 'name',
  data: 'name',
  title: 'Name',
  searchable: true,
  sortable: false,
  render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
    if (type === 'display') {
        var $span = $('<span></span>');
       $('<input type="checkbox">').appendTo($span);
       return $span.html();
    }
    return data;
  }
},
```

here is my code : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/471xf9bg/)

Comment: not able to replicate

Comment: @brk what is problem?

Comment: Also add the code for HTML code for table.

Comment: @Rusty whole of code is on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the states in variable and after drawing table can check and update the state of checkboxes

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jdvusytn/1/

```
function moveRow(row, direction) {
    var index = table.row(row).index();

    var order = -1;
    if (direction === 'down') {
       order = 1;
    }

    var data1 = table.row(index).data();
    data1.order += order;
    var data1Checked = $(table.row(index).node()).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');

    var data2 = table.row(index + order).data();
    data2.order += -order;
    var data2Checked = $(table.row(index + order).node()).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');

    table.row(index).data(data2);
    table.row(index + order).data(data1);

    table.page(0).draw(false);
    $(table.row(index + order).node()).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', data1Checked);
    $(table.row(index).node()).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', data2Checked)
}
```